# implementing a data loading system in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to implement a system in Oracle that will load data from a txt file which will have data in comma separated fields. The txt files will be dumped in a file system location 10-12 times a day but times are not fixed. I am thinking of using external tables to load the data from the txt files to a temp database table and from there to a final table. There may be some invalid data(e.g.  invalid date)  which I need to log and send a mail with those rows included.  Can somebody please suggest an optical way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirment in one of my project and think a  similar approach can be used in your case also, with some modifications  :

a.) Schedule a job to poll the data at fixed intervals to find if a file is present or not.

b.) Once the file is found, use SqlLoader direct path load to get data into a staging table. The insertion scheme for this table will be trunc/insert. Rename the flat file or move it to an archival location, so that it is not picked up again.

c.) The data with invalid format will be recorded in the .bad file generated by sql loader. This can be mailed to business after some formatting.

d.) Move this data to a date partitioned table if you need to maintain a history of data (which is usually needed). You can use partition exchange for this

e.) If you want to use some business logic for marking a data as invalid you can run procedures on these tables to find out invalid records, store them in a table and mail the failed records to the business.

Hope it helps

Vishad